# Install Scipy on shared hosting (godaddy)

Tags: scipy, anaconda, gfortran, shared-hosting

I want to install Scipy on my shared hosting, I've got virtualenv setup with Python 2.7. So in order to install Scipy I need the gfortran installed on my server.

So how can I install gfortran on my shared hosting without root access?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried installing Anaconda? that might be an easy solution to get scipy with all it's dependencies.

Comment: @DavidMaust, I have not, I will try that

Comment: @DavidMaust  I have installed Conda using pip, but when I try to install Scipy using "conda install -n yourenvname [package]" it get the message "/home/yrol/.local/bin/conda: Permission denied". Please help

Comment: Try just downloading their anaconda installer, and see if you can install it that way.

Comment: @DavidMaust thanks, I have installed it using bash and it did install successfully, but when I try create an environment using "conda create -n CondaPython python=2.7 anaconda" I am getting "Error: could not import pycosat (required for dependency resolving)", need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by installing Anaconda distribution as suggested by David Maust.

Steps are as below

1. Download the Anaconda distribution from [here](https://www.continuum.io/downloads#_unix)
2. Install Anaconda - "bash AnacondaX-X.X.X-Linux-x86_64.sh"
3. Setting up the path in .bashrc (in case if not done during the installation) - "export PATH="/home/your_username/your_anaconda_installed_path/bin:$PATH"
4. Starting the Anaconda virtual environment - "source your_anaconda_installed_path/bin/activate ~/your_anaconda_environment_name"

Comment: Where can we find point #4 `your_anaconda_environment_name`?

Comment: I just tried doing this in both BlueHost and GreenGeeks. I get a slew of permissions errors I've never seen before. I've certainly installed conda as non-root before. I think that shared hosting providers are starting to limit what users can do. For instance, in GreenGeeks, I can't even compile `gcc hello.c`.